# Анимация для каждого элемента next() в JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Я хочу добиться эффекта, что при нажатии на элемент icon-menu, каждый пункт li в отдельности последовательно плавно менял совою прозрачность и выезжал слева на право (после выполнения анимации предыдущего элемента) и скрывал иконку самого меню и показывал плавно другую) и при нажатии на элемент .close возникала анимация в обратном направлении.

эффект вроде как получается, но Я не могу добиться чтобы каждый элемент воспроизводил свою анимацию отдельно)

[image: навигация]
     function onShowNavMenu(){
            $('#section-header .icon-menu').animate({
                'opacity':'0',
            },300);

```
        $('#section-header .close').animate({
            'opacity':'1',
            'zIndex':'999',
        },300);

        $('#section-header .menu li').animate({
            'opacity':'0',
            'left':'+=30px',
        },300).next();

    }

    function onCloseNavMenu(){
        $('#section-header .icon-menu').animate({
            'opacity':'1',
        },300);

        $('#section-header .close').animate({
            'opacity':'0',
            'zIndex':'-999',
        },300);

        $('#section-header .menu li').animate({
            'opacity':'0',
            'left':'-=30px',
        },300).next();
    }


<nav role="navigation">
            <div class="close" style="position: absolute; left: 50px; opacity: 0; z-index: -999;" onclick="onCloseNavMenu()"></div>
            <div class="icon-menu" onclick="onShowNavMenu()"></div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li onclick="showMenuItem('service')">Услуги</li>
                <li onclick="showMenuItem('magazine')">Магазин</li>
                <li onclick="showMenuItem('aboot')">О Нас</li>
                <li onclick="showMenuItem('faq')">F.A.Q</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


 #section-header .menu{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}
#section-header .menu li{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #909090;
    margin-right: 35px;
    font-family: calibri-light;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#section-header .menu li:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function onShowNavMenu() {
  $('#section-header .icon-menu').animate({
    'opacity': '0',
  }, 300);

  $('#section-header .close').animate({
    'opacity': '1',
    'zIndex': '999',
  }, 300);

  function showIcon(item) {
    item.animate({
      'opacity': '1',
      'left': '+=30px',
    }, 300, function() {
      showIcon($(this).next())
    });

  }
  showIcon($('#section-header .menu li:first-child'));


}

function onCloseNavMenu() {
  $('#section-header .icon-menu').animate({
    'opacity': '1',
  }, 300);

  $('#section-header .close').animate({
    'opacity': '0',
    'zIndex': '-999',
  }, 300);

  function showIcon(item) {
    item.animate({
      'opacity': '0',
      'left': '-=30px',
    }, 300, function() {
      showIcon($(this).prev())
    });

  }
  showIcon($('#section-header .menu li:last-child'));
}

function showMenuItem() {}
```

```css
.icon-menu {
  background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/roundies-icons/32/menu-128.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.close {
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/roundies-2/32/list-128.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
}
#section-header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
#section-header .menu li {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 17px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #909090;
  margin-right: 35px;
  font-family: calibri-light;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}
#section-header .menu li:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" id="section-header">
  <div class="icon-menu" onclick="onShowNavMenu()"></div>
  <div class="close" onclick="onCloseNavMenu()"></div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li onclick="showMenuItem('service')">Услуги</li>
    <li onclick="showMenuItem('magazine')">Магазин</li>
    <li onclick="showMenuItem('aboot')">О Нас</li>
    <li onclick="showMenuItem('faq')">F.A.Q</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```